# Security message on Windows 10 magnet link

Tags: wpf, security, magnet-uri

I'm working on a WPF/C# application who are exposing commands to be called called by magnet link.

Our application create registry key when msi in installed but, when we use the magnet link, we have a security message each time, even if we check allow access.

Does someone know how we can do to not have this message or at least, just the first time?
We can have dev solution, registry entry, gpo, ...

thanks by advance for any help.

Regards